# GAE Datastore "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property `${property}' contains an invalid nested entity."

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Started receiving an error for the past couple days for persisting nested map structure as an Embedded entity. It was working early without any problem.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property metrics contains an invalid nested entity.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:49)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:97)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$ReorderingMultiFuture.get(Batcher.java:115)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$TxnAwareFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:171)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.TriggerFuture.get(TriggerFuture.java:100)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ResultAdapter.now(ResultAdapter.java:34)
```

Also already that property unindexed. Technically it should ignore the limit of 1500 bytes. I think they made some changes to restrict this.

This error is not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys with dots cannot be used in embedded maps because they have a unique meaning in the new API. If you must have dots in your keys, you can escape them using an @Stringify Stringifier.

Consequently, if you insist on using embedded maps, sanitize to prevent such exceptions.

Found the reason here: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/UpgradeVersion5ToVersion6

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this error could be that you are directly sending protobufs and serialized some bytes that are simply not a valid entity.

Comment: thanks for sharing. found the reason will share here.